# I need to reorganise my excel spreadsheet so i can run some regressions on Stata

Tags: excel, excel-formula

when collecting my data I organized my variables wrong, but it is not a transpose issue. I tried xlookup but one of my arrays is a row instead of a column. I suspect it might be an index job but I am not familiar with it at all.

This is what it currently looks like:

| Company Name | Time Point (t1) | Time Point (t2) | Time Point (t3) | Time Point (t4) | Time Point (t5) | Time Point (t6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company name(1) | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| company name(2) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| company name(3) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| company name(4) |  |  |  |  |  |  |

what I need is:

| Company Name | Time Point | Figure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company name(1) | t(1) | X |
| company name(1) | t(2) | X |
| company name(1) | t(3) | X |
| company name(1) | t(4) | X |
| company name(1) | t(5) | X |
| company name(1) | t(6) | X |
| company name(2) | t(1) | X |
| company name(2) | t(2) | X |
| company name(2) | t(3) | X |
| company name(2) | t(4) | X |
| company name(2) | t(5) | X |
| company name(2) | t(6) | X |
| company name(3) | t(1) | X |
| company name(3) | t(2) | X |
| company name(3) | t(3) | X |
| company name(3) | t(4) | X |
| company name(3) | t(5) | X |
| company name(3) | t(6) | X |
| company name(4) | t(1) | X |
| company name(4) | t(2) | X |
| company name(4) | t(3) | X |
| company name(4) | t(4) | X |
| company name(4) | t(5) | X |
| company name(4) | t(6) | X |

I hope this helps.

I've tried xlookup but I'm not that advanced. the alternative is doing it manually but it's a large dataset.

Comment: how does your data look? please give us an example as code.

Comment: @Mrirrelevant hi, it came out strange the first time i have now added a table instead. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is pivoted, and you want to unpivot it. The best way to do this is in Power Query.

Highlight your data, go to Data, Get & Transform Data from Table/Range. This will turn your data into a table and launch the Power Query editor.

In the Power Query editor, right-click the Company Name column, and click Unpivot Other Columns.

In the image below, the blue table is the original data, the green table is the output after unpivoting.

You can also use Replace Values to get rid of the extra "Time Point" text if you like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided, I would do the following:

1. Put your data into a table.
2. Data > (Get & Transform) From Table
3. Select your Time Point columns
4. Unpivot Columns (in ribbon)
5. Select Attribute column
6. Replace Values & enter "Time Point ".  OK.

You can then rename your columns as desired.  File > Close & Load